# Passing 'Greater than' or 'Less than' operators as parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering can I pass `<` or `>` operators as parameter in SQL Server? I was trying to use a `CASE` statement, but I am receiving an error.

My query looks like this:

```
Select TOP (@messagesNumber)
    * 
from 
    Messages 
Where  
    Case 
       When @action = 'received' Then Addressee 
       When @action = 'sended' Then Sender 
    END = @userId 
    And (CreateDatetime > @fromDate And CreateDateTime < @toDate) 
    And MessageId Case 
                     When @direction = '-1' Then < 
                     When @direction = '--1' Then > 
                  END @startingMessageId 
Order by 
    MessageId * @direction
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP (@messagesNumber) * 
FROM Messages 
WHERE  
     CASE WHEN @action = 'received' THEN Addressee 
          WHEN @action = 'sended' THEN Sender END = @userId 
          AND (CreateDatetime > @fromDate AND CreateDateTime < @toDate) 
          AND ((MessageId < @startingMessageId AND @direction = '-1') OR (MessageId > @startingMessageId AND @direction = '--1')) 
ORDER BY MessageId * @direction
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but with Your solution I'am receiving wrong results. I will try figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a dynamic query like:

```
DECLARE @direction = VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(8000)

SET @direction = '<'
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Price ' + @direction + ' 100'

EXEC(@sql)
```

My query is just an example of usage.